# closed/open classes of Markov Chain

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

$$P^\ast=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} \\
    0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 \\
   \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Determine all open and closed classes.

I am struggling to get my head around the classification of states in a Markov Chain $\{X_t\}_{t\geq0}$. 
I know that $\{6,7\}$ is a closed class as the chain goes to state 7 when initial state is 6 and vice versa. But what about the rest? And would 8 be included in this $\{6,7\}$ class? I am so confused, any help is appreciated!

Update: I have figured out that $C_1=\{6,7,8\}$ is a closed class , and so is $C_2=\{1,3,5\}$ . And a guess would be $C_3=\{4\}$ is open and  $C_4=\{2\}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed classes are $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{6,7\}$. Open classes are $\{2\}$, $\{4\}$ and $\{8\}$.

Comment: why is it that the open classes $\{2\}$, $\{4\}$ and $\{8\}$ are not one class; $\{2,4,8\}$

Comment: Because their communicating classes are empty. They event not communicate with themselves. Such states are called non-return states. They are actually called as non-return sets.